# Slow response from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, performance

In our organisation (located in Melbourne, Australia) we have multiple tenants of SharePoint Online. Since last few weeks we have noticed that one tenant is responding very slow. All other tenants are working fine. Other office 365 services are also working fine. We are trying to identify cause of this problem if it is on our side. It is defiantly not related to our network because other tenants are working fine. Also, because when we try to access our SP site from outside network, it is still slow. We are facing this issue only during 9 am-5 pm. We have already raised it to Microsoft. I need to know:
1.  Is there anything else we can do except raising this issue to Microsoft?
2.  Is there anyone else in the same region who is currently facing same issue?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's nothing you can do outside of Microsoft involvement. The issue is probably not regional, it's more likely related to the farm on which your tenant resides, and if you can convince MS that there is a valid service degradation they can do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not much we can do for this issue. Maybe May need to view the background code to inentify the cause.

So submit a service request in the Microsoft365 admin center > Support > New service request. Ask if they have any useful solution.